# change xml element and attribute names to camelCase

Tags: xml, xslt

i am new to XSLT and am wondering if it is possible to convert XML element and attribute names to camel case ?

My XML payload is like the below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<Output>
    <Error>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <Details>No errors</Details>
    </Error>
    <Synopsis>
        <Count>451</Count>
    </Synopsis>
    <BankAccounts>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="103" CustName="Frank" BalanceAmount="" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>ABC</Address>
                <Address>XYZ</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="101" CustName="Jane" BalanceAmount="10005" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>LMN</Address>
                <Address>QWE</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        
    </BankAccounts>
</Output>
```

Unfortunately i dont have anything to show as i am stumped on how to go about it ....
thanks

Comment: What does that mean for your sample names like `Output` or `BankAccounts`? Changing the first letter to e.g. `o` or `b`? Well, there are string functions like `substring` and there is `translate`, so start learning the XPath string functions, perhaps. Or, if you are using XSLT/XPath 2 or later, look into `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XSLT 2/3 I would use the identity transformation plus templates matching element and attribute nodes that change the first letter using `lower-case`:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{prefix-from-QName(node-name())}{':'[prefix-from-QName(node-name(current()))]}{lower-case(substring(local-name(), 1, 1))}{substring(local-name(), 2)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{prefix-from-QName(node-name())}{':'[prefix-from-QName(node-name(current()))]}{lower-case(substring(local-name(), 1, 1))}{substring(local-name(), 2)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 3 you can set up the identity transformation as the base template by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` (as a top level child of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`), in XSLT 2 you need to spell it out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the role of empty braces?

Comment: @Pavel, you are right, they don't belong in there, I was trying to make the approach namespace proof but got interrupted and later posted that kind of meaningless snippet. Will need to fix it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen what does 'I would use the identity transformation plus templates' mean please ? I am a little confused about what role identity transformation has to play here ?

Answer (score 1):

#### XSLT 1.0, direct approach

You can inline `firstChar` variables, I've introduced them for readability.

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <!--elements-->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        
        <xsl:choose>
            
            <!--elements-->
            <xsl:when test="name() != ''">
                <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="translate(substring(name(),1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz')"/>
                <xsl:element name="{concat($firstChar, substring(name(),2))}">            
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
                </xsl:element>        
            </xsl:when>
            
            <!--values-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--attributes-->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="translate(substring(name(),1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz')"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{concat($firstChar, substring(name(),2))}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### XSLT 1.0, named template for converting a string into camelCase

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <!--elements-->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        
        <xsl:choose>
            
            <!--elements-->
            <xsl:when test="name() != ''">                
                
                <xsl:variable name="newName">
                    <xsl:call-template name="toCamelCase">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="./name()"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>                
                
                <xsl:element name="{$newName}">            
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
                </xsl:element>        
            </xsl:when>
            
            <!--values-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--attributes-->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        
        <xsl:variable name="newName">
            <xsl:call-template name="toCamelCase">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="./name()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>                
        
        <xsl:attribute name="{$newName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--named template that converts a string into camel case-->
    <xsl:template name="toCamelCase">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="translate(substring($value,1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($firstChar, substring($value,2))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <error>
        <status>0</status>
        <details>No errors</details>
    </error>
    <synopsis>
        <count>451</count>
    </synopsis>
    <bankAccounts>
        <bankAccount acctNo="103"
                   custName="Frank"
                   balanceAmount=""
                   inactive="N"
                   noOfAccounts="1">
            <addresses>
                <address>ABC</address>
                <address>XYZ</address>
            </addresses>
        </bankAccount>
        <bankAccount acctNo="101"
                   custName="Jane"
                   balanceAmount="10005"
                   inactive="N"
                   noOfAccounts="1">
            <addresses>
                <address>LMN</address>
                <address>QWE</address>
            </addresses>
        </bankAccount>
        
    </bankAccounts>
</output>
```